# Not able to find the required dependency (jar) in the legacy java code

Tags: java, build, jar, dependencies

I am working on one project which is having legacy java code written around somewhere in 2002.
The code is using below dependency which is not present in our code base. I need to change the code but I am not able to compile/build the code because of the dependency.
**import com.fujitsu.xml.navigator.*;**

Can anyone help me finding this required dependency?
Thanks in advance!

I have searched it on google but couldn't find this dependency.
Can anyone help me finding this required dependency?

Comment: It may help if you share some of the class names in that package -- perhaps the package name has changed.

Comment: Does the project use any build tools like maven or ant? Look for files like pom.xml or build.xml and edit their contents into your question if present.